# Showing Results from Nested Hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, linkedin-api, omniauth

I've successfully implemented the LinkedIn API into my rails app.

The API returns the data from the positions fields which contains more fields from the details of the last 2 positions. It includes title, duration, description, etc...

How do I break this down to get field data set like job title of the second job in my rails app?

For example I want the the title of the second position for one that links to user.positions.title.1

The auth.extra.raw_info.positions.values contains the following in the database

```
[2, [#<OmniAuth::AuthHash company=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id=165676 industry="Marketing and Advertising" name="ReachLocal" size="1001-5000 employees" ticker="RLOC" type="Public Company"> id=666166336 isCurrent=true startDate=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash month=2 year=2015> title="UX/UI Designer">, #<OmniAuth::AuthHash company=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id=1246381 industry="Media Production" name="Freelance" size="Myself Only" type="Self-Employed"> id=561193709 isCurrent=true startDate=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash month=6 year=2014> summary="- Defining business requirements by determining the success metrics, identifying the target demographic, and understanding the project objective/goals \n\n - Conducting evidence-based user research through interviews and usability testing before and after the redesign\n\n - Delivering detailed information architecture, interaction and visual design specifications to stakeholders\n\n - Developing mental models through UX best practices\n\n - Creating actionable and intuitive design flows\n\n - Designing, building, and testing interactive prototypes to iterate and evolve design concepts of the project" title="UX Designer">]]
```

Model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.headline = auth.info.headline
    user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
    user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
    user.industry = auth.info.industry
    user.location = auth.info.location
    user.summary = auth.extra.raw_info.summary
    user.connections = auth.extra.raw_info.numConnections
    user.linkedin_photo_url = auth.info.image
    user.linkedin_url = auth.info.urls.public_profile
    user.linkedin_position = auth.extra.raw_info.positions.values
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an `Array` of length `2`. To get the second element, you can use `[1]`; and `.title` for the title.

Ie: `auth.extra.raw_info.positions.values[1].title`

Note: Indexes start from zero; ie `[0]` is the first element, `[1]` is the second element, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get an undefined method for title. I'm not sure why

Comment: @MattyMatt try `["title"]` instead of `.title`